Real-time Audio Streaming Issue in WebRTC using Python aiortc
I am trying to implement real-time audio streaming between clients using WebRTC with Python's aiortc. For capturing and sending audio, I am using a custom class called MicrophoneAudioTrack. Here’s a brief description of my setup:
Sending Side: I use an instance of MicrophoneAudioTrack that inherits from MediaStreamTrack. It has a recv() method which returns audio bytes captured from the microphone.
Receiving Side: The client is supposed to handle the incoming track using an AudioReceiver class, which also calls the recv() method on the MicrophoneAudioTrack.
The issue I’m facing is that the recv() method works perfectly fine locally on the sender's side, but once I send the track to another client, it stops functioning as expected. The receiving client doesn't seem to process the track data correctly.
Code:
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription, MediaStreamTrack, RTCIceServer, RTCConfiguration

class MicrophoneAudioTrack(MediaStreamTrack):
    kind = "audio"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Initialization of the base class MediaStreamTrack
        self.stream = sd.InputStream(
            channels=1,  # Number of channels (mono)
            samplerate=48000,  # Sample rate
            dtype=np.int16,  # Data type
            callback=self.audio_callback
        )
        self.audio_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.stream.start()

    def audio_callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        if status:
            print(status)
        self.audio_queue.put_nowait(indata.copy())  # Put audio data into the queue

    async def recv(self):
        try:
            print('called recv')
            audio_data = await self.audio_queue.get()  # Wait for data from the queue
            return audio_data.tobytes()  # Return data in bytes format
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("Receiving data was canceled.")

class AudioReceiver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.track = None
        self.output_stream = sd.OutputStream(
            channels=1,  # Number of channels (mono)
            samplerate=48000,  # Sample rate
            dtype=np.int16  # Data type
        )
        self.output_stream.start()

    async def handle_track(self, track):
        print("Inside handle track")
        self.track = track
        while True:
            try:
                audio_data = await track.recv()  # Wait to receive a frame
                # Process the received audio data
                print("Audio data received.")
                audio_array = np.frombuffer(audio_data, dtype=np.int16)
                self.output_stream.write(audio_array)  # Play audio
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

async def signaling(ws, pc):
    """WebSocket signaling handling function"""
    async for message in ws:
        data = json.loads(message)

        if "sdp" in data:
            desc = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=data["sdp"], type=data["type"])

            if desc.type == "offer":
                # Respond to SDP offer
                await pc.setRemoteDescription(desc)
                answer = await pc.createAnswer()
                await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)

                await ws.send(json.dumps({
                    "sdp": pc.localDescription.sdp,
                    "type": pc.localDescription.type
                }))
            elif desc.type == "answer":
                # Handle SDP answer
                await pc.setRemoteDescription(desc)

        elif "candidate" in data:
            candidate = data.get("candidate")
            if candidate:
                ice_candidate = {
                    "candidate": candidate,
                    "sdpMid": data["sdpMid"],
                    "sdpMLineIndex": data["sdpMLineIndex"]
                }
                await pc.addIceCandidate(ice_candidate)

async def run_client():
    # Connect to the signaling server
    ws = await websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8000/ws")

    # Create an RTCPeerConnection with ICE servers (STUN/TURN)
    ice_servers = [
        RTCIceServer(urls="stun:stun.l.google.com:19302")
    ]
    configuration = RTCConfiguration(iceServers=ice_servers)
    pc = RTCPeerConnection(configuration=configuration)

    # Create a microphone audio track object and add it to the RTCPeerConnection
    microphone_track = MicrophoneAudioTrack()
    pc.addTrack(microphone_track)

    # Flag to track the ICE connection state
    ice_connection_ready = asyncio.Event()

    # Create an object for track playback
    audio_receiver = AudioReceiver()

    @pc.on("track")
    async def on_track(track):
        if isinstance(track, MediaStreamTrack):
            await ice_connection_ready.wait()
            print(f"Receiving {track.kind} track")
            asyncio.ensure_future(audio_receiver.handle_track(track))

    @pc.on("icecandidate")
    async def on_icecandidate(candidate):
        if candidate:
            await ws.send(json.dumps({
                "candidate": candidate.candidate,
                "sdpMid": candidate.sdpMid,
                "sdpMLineIndex": candidate.sdpMLineIndex
            }))

    @pc.on("iceconnectionstatechange")
    async def on_iceconnectionstatechange():
        print(f"ICE connection state changed to {pc.iceConnectionState}")
        if pc.iceConnectionState in ("connected", "completed"):
            ice_connection_ready.set()  # Set the flag when the connection is ready

    # Check if there is already a saved SDP offer on the server
    await ws.send(json.dumps({"request_offer": True}))
    response = await ws.recv()
    data = json.loads(response)

    if "sdp" in data and data["type"] == "offer":
        # Receive the SDP offer and create an answer
        desc = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=data["sdp"], type="offer")
        await pc.setRemoteDescription(desc)
        answer = await pc.createAnswer()
        await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)

        # Send the SDP answer to the server
        await ws.send(json.dumps({
            "sdp": pc.localDescription.sdp,
            "type": pc.localDescription.type
        }))
    else:
        # Initialize the session by creating an SDP offer
        offer = await pc.createOffer()
        await pc.setLocalDescription(offer)
        await ws.send(json.dumps({
            "sdp": pc.localDescription.sdp,
            "type": "offer"
        }))

    # Further exchange of ICE candidates and signaling
    await signaling(ws, pc)

    # Close the connection after completion
    await pc.close()

# Start the main event loop
asyncio.run(run_client())

I already verified that the recv() method works when used locally on the sender's machine.
Any suggestions or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated!
